# How is the notion of a Lipschitz structure on a manifold defined?

Tags: manifolds, metric-spaces, uniform-spaces

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity#Lipschitz_manifolds), there is such a definition. $\:$ The candidate that I can come up with is

"an equivalence class of metrics that induce the topology and make the space locally bi-Lipschitz

to Euclidean space with its usual metric, where the equivalence relation is [Lipschitz-equivalence](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition%3aLipschitz_Equivalence#Metrics)".

However, I worry that that definition might be too restrictive.

(There is an obvious way to define a $\hspace{.02 in}\it{locally}$-Lipschitz structure on a manifold,

almost identically to how a differentiable structure is defined, but that's $\it{not}$ what I'm interested in.)

Comment: The use of the word "pseudo-group" makes clear, I think, that the wikipedia writer has in mind the definition of analogous to that of a differentiable structure, based on bi-Lipschitz homeomorphisms of open subsets in $\mathbb{R}^n$. So I'm a bit puzzled by your question which seems to me to be asking the meaning of the wikipedia definition but also rejecting the answer...

Comment: If it does indeed mean that, then I suppose the article could be more clear. $\hspace{1.91 in}$

Comment: @TimPerutz The problem is that on a noncompact manifold, locally Lipschitz functions need not be Lipschitz.

Comment: To help you more context is needed. What do you want this kind of structure for? Why is the local definition not suitable for your purpose? You say that your proposed definition might be too restrictive, what kind of phenomenon or example do you fear it to prevent?

Comment: I was mainly interested in whether or not there were any examples that were not equivalent to a submanifold of Euclidean space with its induced Lipschitz structure. $\:$ The local-Lipschitz structure does not determine the [uniform structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space) or [what sets are bounded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bornological_space). $\;\;\;$

Comment: Intuitively, I worry that my definition might not allow for stitching together finitely many such manifolds when it should. $\:$ More formally, I worry that there might be a manifold with finitely many (compatible) bounded metrics on open subsets such that each pair of them are bi-Lipschitz on the intersection of their open subsets and for some positive $r$, for every point $x$ on the manifold, one of those metrics is such that $B(r,x)$ (with respect to that metric) is a compact subset of that metric's domain, but there is no global metric equivalent to all of those finitely many metrics. $\;$

Comment: Ricky, Will: I see what you mean. Philosophically, I think the idea of the notion of Lipschitz manifold belongs not so much to the world of metric spaces but on the scale of manifolds of various degrees of regularity: real analytic, $C^\infty$ and $C^1$ manifolds are all essentially the same; what happens if one relaxes things further by going down to locally Lipschitz maps? (And now things do break.)

Answer (score 7):

There are two fundamental papers on this subject: [Hyperbolic geometry and homeomorphisms](http://kssarkaria.org/docs/Sullivan.pdf) by Sullivan, and [Quasiconformal 4-manifolds](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02392736#page-1) by Donaldson and Sullivan. The follow-up paper [Lipschitz and quasiconformal approximation of homeomorphism pairs](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864199001455) is also relevant. All go well beyond just the definition, which is fairly obvious.

Edit 1. I realized that I misread your question. The real answer is that the category you are interested in is equivalent to the locally Lipschitz (LL) one. Namely, every LL manifold M admits a locally bilipschitz embedding $i$ in the Euclidean space of some high dimension. Now, induce the path metric on M using the ambient Euclidean metric, i.e. define distance between points as infimum of Euclidean lengths of paths in $i(M)$ connecting these points. Then the resulting metric will satisfy your requirements. Conversely, if you have a metric on  n-manifold satisfying your requirements, then it defines a LL atlas via bilipschitz local maps to $R^n$.

Edit 2. Here is a sketch how of you can glue together charts with different metrics while preserving the (global) bilipschitz (BL) structure, which seems to be one of your concerns (expressed in the comments). I will work with the path-metrics, which is natural in your case as you want your metrics to be locally BL to the Euclidean metric. Using the LL atlas that you have, you define rectifiable curves in a LL manifold $X$ as curves which are rectifiable in the charts (this is well-defined) and I will assume that the length structure is defined via such curves which is again natural. Given a length structure on a space $X$, you also have the notion of the integral $\int_c f(x)ds$ for continuous functions $f$ along rectifiable curves $c$. Now, given your charts $U_i$, you can define a (globally) Lipschitz partition of unity $\eta_i$ (using "distance functions to the boundary"- you have to adjust such functions slightly since your charts might be unbounded). Let I will use the notation $\int_c f(x) ds_i$ to denote the integral with respect to the length structure $\lambda_i$ coming from the $i$-th chart. Now, you define a length structure $\lambda$ on your space $X$ (it does not have to be a manifold) by
$$
\int_c ds= \sum_{i} \int_c \eta_i(x) ds_i. 
$$
Since your length structures were assumed to be BL-equivalent (this follows from BL equivalence of the distance functions), we conclude for each $i$, the restriction of $\lambda$ to $U_i$ is BL-equivalent to the length structure $\lambda_i$:
$$
C^{-1}\int_c ds_i\le \int_c ds\le C \int_c ds_i, \forall i. 
$$ 
Therefore, if you define the distance function $d_X$ on $X$ using the length structure $\lambda$, the restriction of $d_X$ to each $U_i$ is BL equivalent to the initial distance function on $U_i$.

Comment: You say that "is fairly obvious". $\:$ Do you mean they are referring to locally-Lipschitz structures, $\hspace{.79 in}$ they are using the candidate I suggested, or something else? $\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer: Yes, they are using the locally Lipschitz notion. Requiring global Lipschitz bounds would not be useful since you want your charts to be local and you want the CAT map between CAT-manifolds to be defined by a local property. Here CAT is any category in the sense of Kirby and Siebenmann.

Comment: It seems to me like, for every non-compact locally-Lipschitz manifold $M$, there will be such embeddings that induce different global-Lipschitz structures on $M$. $\:$ Thus, I don't see how your argument shows an equivalence of categories. $\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer: That's correct. I am using the local biLipschitz equivalence relation. In any case, as far as the existence problem you worried about, you get the existence theorem for every LL structure. I do not know what else you might be asking for. I do not know how would you prescribe a global BL behavior for a metric in this context. If you have a more specific question, you should ask one.