# What is the name for a set endowed with a Lipschitz structure?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry

I am interested in the standard (or widely accepted) name for a mathematical structure, which is intermediate between the structures of a metric space and a topological space. I have in mind the Lipschitz structure (which is invariant under bi-Lipschitz transformations of metric spaces).

By a *Lipschitz structure* on a set $X$ we understand a maximal family $\mathcal L$ of bi-Lipschitz equivalent metrics on $X$.

A *Lipschitz space* is a pair $(X,\mathcal L)$ consisting of a set $X$ and a Lipschitz structure $\mathcal L$ on $X$.

Is this terminology standard or used by some authors?
If yes, could you provide a reference.
If not, what is the alternative terminology for such kind of structure?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a common name. I think the convenient language is the categorical language, which comes with considering the category of metric spaces and Lipschitz maps, and for which there's no need to consider maximal (or rather saturated) families of metrics.

Comment: But in the case of the topological structure the notion of topology was invented and this turned to be more general than just a set with a maximal family of topologically equivalent metric. The same situation with the uniformity.

Comment: If you are willing to restrict yourself to the case where $X$ is a manifold, this topic was discussed in another MO question, with references to work of Sullivan and Donaldson: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/146678/how-is-the-notion-of-a-lipschitz-structure-on-a-manifold-defined

Comment: @LeeMosher No, may motivation came from the theory of fractals. I am interested in spaces bi-Lipschitz (or bi-Holder) equivalent to fractals. They are very far from being manifolds.

Comment: Is there anything to stop us from just calling it a "Lipschitz space"?

Comment: Just to illustrate my previous comment: I think that a topological space with the good condition and endowed with an atlas (etc) is a correct definition of smooth manifold, and that there is no need to consider maximal atlases, which was possibly fashionable 60 years ago. The categorical language (of the category of manifolds with smooth maps) is enough to formulate all we usually want, notably to naturally set up the notion of classification up to diffeomorphism, etc... (except possibly in some purely set-theoretic considerations of not much geometric relevance, though).

Comment: @YCor Of course the whole theory can be developed in the category of metric spaces and suitable morphisms. But the philosophy of the development of mathematics shows that morphisms appear first and then force to introduce the general notion of objects possessing the structure, which is preserved by that kind of morphisms. Exactly this happened with topological spaces, uniform spaces, coarse spaces, smooth manifolds, linear spaces, etc. Even the notion of a set was invented after the notion of a function. Why the Lipschitz category should be an exception?

Comment: Check out my question here, it’s kind of similar: mathoverflow.net/q/319737/5017

Comment: Just a comment that the term "Lipschitz space" already has an established  meaning as a Banach space of Lipschitz functions on a metric space.

Answer (score 4):

In the theory of quasiconformal and quasisymmetric mappings on metric spaces, the collection of metrics that are quasisymmetric to a given metric on a space is sometimes called a ``conformal gauge''. (See, e.g., Heinonen's *Lectures on Analysis on Metric Spaces*.) You could therefore try "Lipschitz gauge" or "bi-Lipschitz gauge", but to be honest I have never heard these terms used (and maybe they are already used for something else).

Answer (score 1):

These spaces were introduced by Whitehead and called "locally metric spaces" by Luukkainen and Väisälä. See the precise references in the answer to [Objects whose morphisms are Lipschitz maps](https://mathoverflow.net/q/258108/57323).

This is assuming that by "Lipschitz" you mean "locally Lipschitz", so the resulting spaces are not necessarily metric spaces, and there is no notion of "bounded subset".

Comment: The notion is very natural with Lipschitz, so there no reason to assume to believe that the OP meant something else. So I don't think this answers the question.